# what are the required resources (CPU and RAM usage) of server to handle nearly 1 million user with Strongloop-Loopback

Tags: node.js, nginx, load-balancing, loopbackjs, strongloop

We have a project that may involve nearly one million users (simple REST API connecting with mongodb) and wonder what kind of server we need (CPU/MEM/BW required etc.) and does Strongloop PM enough (slc arc build && deploy)? Should I use other software like nginx?

Another small question is the "processes set in Strongloop PM". Should it be set to N-1 where N is the CPU number as we generally do in nginx?

Comment: 1 million user concurrently or daily or yearly?

Comment: You should probably use nginx (or haproxy or...?) but it depends on what the API is serving up, but a reverse proxy is usually beneficial for caching and load balancing precisely for scaling reasons.

Comment: 1M daily and in case that probably they query at the same time (though maybe 10K-100K generally). What troubles me is whether one server enough with nginx or how should I learn how to config more than one node? This project is too hug for me, So I really lose my head.